# I want to use res.sendfile but the path is not correct error comes up

Tags: javascript, html, express, frontend, backend

I have a server Express.js and 3 html, JS frontend pages I want to access my homepage in localhost:3000 and then go to /register to render my register.html page but I can't do the path here is a screenshot of my folder 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShrWP.png)
and Here is my code

```
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "./FRONT/REGISTER/register.html")
```

This Gives me an error :
{"error":{"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/hazem/Desktop/Web-Development/full-stack-blogs/api/routes../FRONT/REGISTER/register.html'"}}

Also It gives me an error that app is not defined in my registerUsers.js :

Here are my Routes --> registerUsers.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.json());
// Handle incoming post requests to /register
router.post('/register',(req,res,next)=>{
    const user= {
        userName:req.userName,
        email:req.email,
        password:req.password,
        sex:req.sex
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        message:"Handling post requests to /register",
        user:user
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app is undefined because you didn't import this like `const app = require('path of your app file`); also make sure you do `module.exports = app;` in your app.js file or another way to export it.

From what file do you use this `res.sendFile(__dirname + "./FRONT/REGISTER/register.html")` ? Please also use the path module from nodeJs to create your paths (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

If you use this statement from registerUsers.js your path should be : `path.join(__dirname, "../FRONT/REGISTER/register.html);` note the **../**

You would import path like : `const path = require('path');` and use it with your res.sendFile like this:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "FRONT/REGISTER/register.html"));
```

I hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: Yes this helped a lot , Thank you!! , I solved the path issue but It now renders without the CSS file , I don't know why Although Its imported in the HTML file

Comment: Please take a look at the path from within your html file.

Comment: What do you mean? I fixed the path in my Backend and now the html file renders but without my CSS  , although it is linked right and when I render the html page alone without the server in google chrome it is rendered with the CSS , Thank you for your help.   GET http://localhost:3000/register.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404. &&& GET http://localhost:3000/register.CSS net::ERR_ABORTED 404(NOT FOUND) , this what I get in the console

Comment: Okay, then the problem is that you have to serve your public directory. Like this: app.use(express.static(path.join('directory where css file is')); then it should work. If the answer solved your problem please accept, it.

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem but I still can't do it right                                  `//Routing HomePage 
  app.get('/',(req,res,next)=> {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'FRONT')));
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/FRONT/home.html");

  })` Where exactly Should I include the app.use express.static as it gives an error if its inside or outside the app.get

Comment: You should do this in your app file. Put it under this line const app = express();
It doesn't really matter where you put it but in the root of your application. Do not put it in a route